# How to set DataContext Binding on Style, Setter and HierarchicalDataTemplate for sub properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

If I set the DataContext of a Window using

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    readonly TreeViewViewModel TreeView;
    public MainWindow()
    {
      //...
      this.DataContext = TreeView;
    }       
}
```

then the following XAML works fine

```
<TreeView x:Name="radTreeView" Grid.Row="1"
                     Margin = "5,5,5,5"
                     ItemsSource = "{Binding FirstGeneration}"
                     Padding = "5"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = "Visible"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = "Visible"
                     IsTextSearchEnabled="True" >
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" >
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

However, I need the DataContext to be a property of a ViewModel so that `TreeViewViewModel TreeView` is a property of `MainViewModel mainViewModel` and the DataContext set in codebehind as

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainViewModel mainViewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
      //...
      this.DataContext = this;
    }       
}
```

I can get parts of the binding working using `DataContext = "{Binding MainViewModel.TreeView}"` but this only works on the main TreeView element and not the  Style, Setter, HierarchicalDataTemplate which don't have a DataContext property.

How do I correctly set the data context for all of the XAML TreeView elements?

Below is what I have tried so far but only `ItemsSource = "{Binding FirstGeneration}"` is working with the correct data context

```
<TreeView x:Name="radTreeView" Grid.Row="1"
                     Margin = "5,5,5,5"
                     DataContext = "{Binding MainViewModel.TreeView}"
                     ItemsSource = "{Binding FirstGeneration}"
                     Padding = "5"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = "Visible"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = "Visible"
                     IsTextSearchEnabled="True" >
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" >
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: My code does actually work okay (doh!) - for simplicity in writing this question I removed DataContext from the CheckBox and TextBox which now works fine in code. dkozl's answer helped dugug the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `DataContext` of the container for `radTreeView` is an instance of `MainViewModel` you can do

```
<TreeView ... DataContext="{Binding TreeView}" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration}">
```

or without changing `DataContext`

```
<TreeView ... ItemsSource="{Binding TreeView.FirstGeneration}">
```

Comment: I think the problem is that I was trying to set the DataContext on the Treeview element and also on the sub elements at the same time. Does that mean DataContext is hierarchical and has a path back through the parent controls?

Comment: Yes, `DataContext` is inherited down the visual tree until it will be changed either manually in XAML or for example `ItemsControl` will set `DataContext` of each item container to item of the list